# Pruning chili plant

Tags: houseplants, pruning, chili

I have grown a chili plant from seeds. It grows fine but I think it getting too tall compared to the width (now at 22 cm/8.5 in). How should I prune it to get a nice dense plant?

[image: Chili plant]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pruning is often performed right above a leave node or branch. I thought my avocado's died after pruning them. I did it in December and earlier. Months of nothing happening (the one pruned earliest had something growing, but stopped). A few weeks ago, with the nice weather, growth has been going on like crazy. After some research, it seems that unless you live in a place where weather is similar all year round, you should take into account the year season, and it is like this I'd say for most plants. But I haven't found a lot of information about it, a few articles like below, and personal experience.

> "There are two primary timeframes for pruning peppers: during the establishment period in spring, and late in the season when the threat of frost closes in." [Ref: How to prune pepper plants](https://www.southernliving.com/garden/edible/how-to-prune-pepper-plants#:%7E:text=Prune%20plants%20heavily%20by%20cutting,ripen%20before%20the%20first%20frost.).

If you have a pruning tool, better. Place it right above a leave node or branch, and prune.

[image]

In [here](https://peppergeek.com/pruning-pepper-plants/) they explain that for peppers, it can be done in a few timeframes of the plant, for different results. Check it out!

> We recommend pruning young peppers just above the 3rd or 4th node, counting up from the bottom. This will allow more light to reach lower nodes, triggering new growth from below. Note: This method is also called topping pepper plants, as you are essentially cutting the top of the plant off.

> Many pepper varieties have a tendency to grow tall and lanky, especially with inadequate lighting. Pruning can also help keep your plants a manageable size while they are indoors.